# Jenkins for loop exeucting even is empty list

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

H. as i see when it is empty also it is printing empty. How to avoid the echo print if it is empty?

```
                    for (SubjectList in Subject.split('\r?\n'))
                    {
                      sh "echo '1${SubjectList }2'"                   
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use tokenize() instead:

```
for (SubjectList in Subject.tokenize('\r?\n'))
{
    sh "echo '1${SubjectList }2'"                   
}
```

I don't know what `\r?\n` means but if you want to split it by newlines you can just use `Subject.tokenize()` (without parameters)

> The split() method returns a string [] instance and the  tokenize() method returns a list instance
> tokenize() ,which returns a list, will ignore empty string (when a delimiter appears twice in  succession) where as split() keeps such string.